# How can I Reload custom Popup when ajax Success In Magento2?

Tags: magento2

**strong text**I Have Custom Popup with Special Products when Someone Click On Add to cart On Category Page Product than Popup Open and They Show Special Products So The Problem is When i add To Cart Product From Popup than It Not add in Popup Real Time What Can I Do ? Below Is My code

[image]

```
$('.popupaddtocart').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var baseUrl = urlBuilder.build('');
            var productId = $(this).find('#popupproductid').text();
            var requestURL = baseUrl + 'popupwithslider/popup/productaddtocart';
            var info = "";
            $.ajax({
                url: requestURL,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    productId: productId,
                },
                showLoader: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    var sections = ['cart'];
                    customerData.reload(sections, true);

                    if (response.success) {
                        if (response.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
                            $(".updatemessage")
                                .css("visibility", "visible")
                                .addClass("message-success success message")
                                .html("Item Inserted Successfully");
                        } else if (response.hasOwnProperty('url')) {
                            window.location.href = response.url;
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.error('Error adding product to cart.');
                    }
                error: function () {
                    console.error('Error adding product to cart.');
                }
            });
        });
```